# is there any other standard to normalize timstamp other than mini max and standard scaling?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

by using the min max technique my Ai model is not learning efficiently because of which the validation loss is too high (0.3234) and is not bearable.

i tried many loss function MSE, MAE, many other functions like that, but the results remained the same. I want the validation loss to be closest to zero.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.